# How EC2 auto scaling prevent to launch a new one until overhead?

Tags: amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I have an existed EC2 instance running(say original one).

Then I created a auto-scaling group and configured its launch settings like below:
**min:1, max:3, desired:1**
(The auto-scaling group is based on a AMI which copied from original instance)

As soon as I just created the auto scaling group, a new instance launching at the same time.
But my existed instance is running idle without any overhead issue currently, so it is not necessary to launch a new one within the auto scaling group.

I tried to set desired to 0 currently, then the launched one is terminated and left my original existed one running.

So, **min:1,desired:0**, is the right way to prevent to launch a new one until overhead?
Or any advice, please?

By the way, I have no any overhead process now, so it is hard for me to confirm the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best would be to register your original instance manually to the autoscaling group.

This will simplify things with numbers (you can say min:1, max:3, desired:1 and the original one is already counted as 1 so you would get the result that you expect) and also will make easier to control target group and route the traffic properly to all instances from the ELB

To attach an instance to an existing Auto Scaling group:

- Open the Amazon EC2 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/
- On the navigation pane, choose Instances.
- Select the instance.
- Choose Actions, Instance Settings, Attach to Auto Scaling Group.
- On the Attach to Auto Scaling Group page, select an existing Auto Scaling group, select the instance, and then choose Attach.

If you want your original instance to be always alive -dont be terminated in downscaling- you can enable termination protection for a running or stopped instance

- Select the instance, and choose Actions, Instance Settings, Change Termination Protection
- Choose Yes, Enable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
Because I don't want to stop my original instance, if I followed your instructions to set desired from 0 currently to 1, Could I image the next actions, please?
First a new instance would be launched, 
Then I add the original one into the ASG(so there would be two instances running at the moment?),
Finally which one would be terminated automatically?

Comment: There are different criteria for terminating instances -zone with more instances, older launch config, etc...-. In your case, being only two and with same launch configuration, most probably the one closer to the next billing hour will be terminated, which is not easy for you to forecast. BUT remember that you can protect termination of your original instance so that one will stay running ways and the scale in will not terminate it, the system will chose always a different one to terminate. See the update in the response